# Screen distorts after enlarging/opening new windows

Tags: windows, distort

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XriOo.jpg]
This distortion occurs upon opening new windows inside blender, such that I can not save, save rendered image, open project, virtually anything. I'd really appreciate an answer on how to fix this issue, since it disables me from working in the app as a whole.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QQ76.jpg]

Also, when I open the app in full screen mode, the same distortion happens and after quitting full screen I am only able to work in the 3D viewport

Comment: That is graphic card drivers / non supported graphic card problem... Try to update drivers for GPU or use another GPU if your PC has one. Also to make screenshots use https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html

Comment: If your laptop is an Acer Nitro 5, then all models come with a graphics cards  from the Nvidia Geforce 10 series which are supported by Blender. Download the latest driver for your graphics card directly from Nvidia: https://www.nvidia.de/Download/index.aspx?lang=en